# How to control existing button with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, hardware, pi-pico

I've got a simple standing with two buttons up/down. It has built in overload protection, i.e. when it's blocked. I'm pretty sure the controller behind the up/down button does that.

As my first Pico project I want to add memory control to it, and optionally having it go from standing to sitting and vice versa every 45-60 minutes.

I got most of it in my head, but I'm not sure how to control the motor. I don't want to send power directly to the motor, as that bypasses the overload protection I believe.

Based on [this post](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-set-my-desk-to-standing-mode-b21dcc40d4b5) I thought the easiest would be to connect the Pico to the Up and Down button. In that post, it's using a "NPN Transistor Switching Circuit" but that seems overkill to me.
Isn't there an easier way to trigger the up/down button? I was thinking to connect a GPIO to  one of the pins of each of the two buttons and then send a 1 (or 0)? 1 to the Up button to go up, 1 to the Down button to go down.
See [here a photo of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rxXv.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do first, is to check what is the voltage between the contacts which button closes. Second you need to check how much current will go through the button when it is closed. To do so, you can simply short the button contacts with an ammeter. If both match your Pi GPIO ratings, then you can try using Pi to control buttons directly. Note, Pi should be able to supply in this case the amount of current you have measured. Make sure Pi and button circuits are connected to the same ground.

In any case, a better way is to use a switch circuit. It is safer for your circuits and it can be designed for essentially any voltage and current. It can be a regular transistor, relay, or better a MOSFET. For that you still want to check voltage and current at the button as described above, and select a MOSFET with matching ratings with the button and your Pi GPIO. In order to build a circuit it is good to understand transistor (or MOSFET) basics, [this GreatScott video](https://youtu.be/o4_NeqlJgOs) can be a good start and can be used as instructions.

Comment: **Current** goes through, not **power**. A switch typically dissipates almost zero power...it is the current and voltage, separately, that we care about.

Comment: True. I should have used current instead of power in the first passage. Edited.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim that makes perfect sense! 
Yeah, my worry is that by connecting directly it'll blow the board possibly. A switch makes more sense. I read about NPN transistors to achieve this, will read about MOSFET too and watch that video. I'm learning more and more.

Your post was much appreciated. Thanks.